# Utilizando setContentView em métodos estáticos

Tags: android, arquitetura-de-software

Estou criando uma aplicação com utilização do Bluetooth, onde o método que recebe as mensagens é `static`.

Dependendo da mensagem que o dispositivo receber, gostaria que a aplicação realizasse algo além de simplesmente mostrar a mensagem num `textView` (também `static`) na tela, como por exemplo chamar uma outra tela (`setContentView`), criar uma `Intent` qualquer ou apresentar um `AlertDialog.Builder`.

O problema se dá quando um método `static` tenta utilizar-se desses recursos. Tentei através desse método `static` criar um objeto da classe `ActivityMain` para utilizar um outro método qualquer que realizasse esse processo, entretanto, também ocorre erros.

O que fazer?

Comment: Me parece que sua arquitetura contém problemas estruturais sérios. `View` estática é um mal sinal. Criar manualmente objetos do tipo `Activity` (em vez de requisitar ao sistema através  do `startActivity`) é um _péssimo_ sinal. Acho que precisaremos de mais detalhes sobre sua arquitetura atual para entendermos melhor o que sugerir.

Comment: Bom! Vou tentar apresentar o problema de uma forma mais simples.
Temos a classe principal:

Comment: Temos um metodo STATIC sendo iniciado

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Vou chamar um metodo static
        inicio();
    }}

Comment: private static void inicio() {
        // Nenhuma das tentativas compilam...

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("titulo");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK",null);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, outraActivity.class);
        // Uma opção seria...
        // Instanciar um objeto dessa classe para utilizar um metodo NÃO      STATIC
        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        mainActivity.chamarOutraTela();
    }

Comment: private void chamarOutraTela(){
        // Aqui todas tentativas acima compilam... entretanto também NAÕ FUNCIONAM
        // O App trava ao executar
    }